# Fully Removing/Disabling Crash Kernel

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, grub2, kernel

While diagnosing a problem with a Ubuntu system I installed `linux-crashdump` to try to capture logs in case they could give me useful hints about what was happening.

After resolving the issue, a few months later I removed `linux-crashdump`, however I still seem to have a lot of `crashkernel=` options in my boot arguments:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-145-generic root=UUID=760048a7-4ab2-47e0-9a0d-ad961df07974 ro console=ttyS0 rootwait crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-:128M crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M
```

Not sure how it's become as messy as it is, but I'd like to get rid this to make certain no memory is being allocated for something that is no longer installed.

I believe these arguments are located in the file `/boot/grub/grub.cf`, but given how critical a part of the system this is I'm wary about just deleting stuff.

So my question is; what is the correct way to fully remove these `crashkernel=` arguments (or reset to defaults) and is there anything else I should check to make sure my system is cleaned of crash kernel behaviour?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.6 LTS

I installed `linux-crashdump` using the instructions found here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

Essentially just `sudo apt-get install linux-crashdump`

I used `sudo apt-get remove linux-crashdump` to uninstall it

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/default/grub` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is autogenerated: do not manually edit it! The proper way to customize your grub installation is to modify `/etc/default/grub` (and any configuration file under `/etc/default/grub.d`, if they exist) and run `update-grub` as root when done.